# command not found after installing with npm

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, npm, osx-yosemite

Thanks in advance for looking at my post!

**Main Questions:**

1. What do I have to do to get http-server found when I call it from the command line?
2. I feel this issue has revealed my linux incompetence. If I wanted to start from scratch with node and home brew, what files and directories would I have to remove (or make sure they have been removed by an uninstall command) before proceeding?

Thanks in advance!

**Background**

After I thought I fixed home brew (OS X 10.10 uses a newer version of Ruby), I tried reinstalling http-server with npm after I got the message `-bash: http-server: command not found`. So I ran `sudo npm install -g http-server`. Then I get a screen with lines that contain `npm http GET https://registry/npmjs.org/` and `npm http 304 https://registry/npmjs.org/`.  The latter are followed by `~.node/bin/http-server -> ~.node/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server' and 'http-server@0.7.3 ~.node/lib/node_modules/http-server`.

**Notes**

1. I found this `/usr/local/bin/http-server@`, which I believe is the symbolic link for http-server.
2. It appears that the link `http-server -> ../lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server` does not exist, and I can't figure out why.
3. The folder `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/http-server` does have `0.6.1` and `0.7.3`
4. The directory `0.7.3`  just has a package directory followed by a package.json file. I'm confused as I would have expected this to contain more than just a package.json.
5. I believe brew is installed correctly because  `which brew` gives `/usr/local/bin/brew`
6. Also, I get `brew -v Homebrew 0.9.5`
7. `which npm` gives `/usr/local/bin/npm` (This is also the same for node)
8. `npm -v`gives `1.4.28`
9. My Path variable is listed as in item 10 (broken out so it's more readable), below.
10. - $HOME/.npm (I manually put this here, see 11 below for why)
    - /bin
    - /sbin
    - /usr/bin
    - /usr/sbin
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /usr/local/mysql/bin
    - /opt/X11/bin
11. It appears that $Home/.npm has a list of packages that I've installed with npm. I thought that if I put $Home/.npm it may see http-server, which is in this directory. But it appears to be in the same structure as noted in point #4, above.
12. I'm using OS X 10.10
13. Yesterday I installed X Code 6.1 because apparently it was required due to a command line issue.

Answer (score 1):

#### Global installation

Did you install `http-server` with npm globally?

To install a module globally (which you need for a CLI), you must enable the global flag:

`npm install -g http-server`

#### npm scripts

It is also possible to install CLI modules locally, and run them from npm scripts.

In your `package.json`:

```
...
devDependencies: {
    "http-server": "^0.8.5"
},
scripts: {
    "serve": "http-server ./public"
}
...
```

then

```
http-server ./public
# unsuccessful

npm run serve
# successful
```